# Trying to groupby Pyspark df without aggregation (i think)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to groupby the following pyspark dataframe to combine the renewal_mo values but can't seem to figure it out.

I have this dataframe:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|First_Purchase|Renewal_Mo|second_buy|third_buy|fourth_buy|fifth_buy|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|6             |1         |1         |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |12        |36        |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |24        |4         |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |18        |2         |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |3         |6         |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |2         |8         |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |36        |1         |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |6         |12        |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |12        |0         |1        |0         |0        |
|6             |3         |0         |1        |0         |0        |
|6             |2         |0         |7        |0         |0        |
|6             |6         |0         |1        |0         |0        |
|6             |1         |0         |0        |1         |0        |
|6             |12        |0         |0        |1         |0        |
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

and would like to combine the values in renewal_mo so there are no duplicates and produce this dataframe:

```
|First_Purchase|Renewal_Mo|second_buy|third_buy|fourth_buy|fifth_buy|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|6             |1         |1         |0        |1         |0        |
|6             |12        |36        |1        |1         |0        |
|6             |24        |4         |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |18        |2         |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |3         |6         |1        |0         |0        |
|6             |2         |8         |7        |0         |0        |
|6             |36        |1         |0        |0         |0        |
|6             |6         |12        |1        |0         |0        |
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

But groupby seems to be the wrong approach as it requires passing an aggregate function. Can I use windows partition somehow? Might there be some other way?  What am I missing here?

If I try

```
foo.groupby('First_Purchase','Renewal_Mo').count().show(truncate=False)
```

I lose the buy columns of course and it only counts the instances of the Renewal_Mo. I am not sure how to approach this to get the desired dataframe immediately above

```
+--------------+----------+-----+
|First_Purchase|Renewal_Mo|count|
+--------------+----------+-----+
|6             |1         |2    |
|6             |12        |3    |
|6             |24        |1    |
|6             |18        |1    |
|6             |3         |2    |
|6             |2         |2    |
|6             |36        |1    |
|6             |6         |2    |
+--------------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think that the `groupBy` is reasonable.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import builtins as p

df.groupBy('First_Purchase', 'Renewal_Mo') \
  .agg(*[max(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns[2:]]) \
  .show()

+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|First_Purchase|Renewal_Mo|second_buy|third_buy|fourth_buy|fifth_buy|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|             6|         1|         1|        0|         1|        0|
|             6|        12|        36|        1|         1|        0|
|             6|        24|         4|        0|         0|        0|
|             6|        18|         2|        0|         0|        0|
|             6|         3|         6|        1|         0|        0|
|             6|         2|         8|        7|         0|        0|
|             6|        36|         1|        0|         0|        0|
|             6|         6|        12|        1|         0|        0|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: I like your alias approach. I am not sure on how max factors in. getting this error: ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'alias'```

Comment: Might be the max function is recognized by the built-in python function. Try to rename it .

Comment: I imported max and it worked fine. Do you mind explaining the logic here? ```agg(*[min(c)```   I am trying to understand how max summed up the values.

Comment: `[max...]` is a list and `*` will explode it to the individual values by comma-separated. So it is same as the `.agg(max(col1).alias(col1), max(col2).alias(col2), ...)`.

Comment: Shouldnt it be sum() instead of max()?

Comment: Sum doesn't seem to work.  I think max works because every cell is unique. There is nothing to sum per se. So by calling max every value is max. But I am still trying to understand it. If I could figure out how to see how the * explodes the max list that might clear it up for me. Haven't figured that out yet.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why you say that groupby is a wrong approach since it needs an aggregate function.
The only way I would do it is grouping and aggregating, there is a built in function sum that does exactly what you want:

```
df.groupBy('First_Purchase','Renewal_Mo') \
    .agg({'second_by': 'sum',
          'third_by':  'sum'}) # So on with remaining columns
```

The only thing it happends is that this method changes the column names but you can easily solve it with multiple approaches.